# Google Task API isn't listing all my tasklist

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

I tried with OAuth Playground, it's running fine and returning me all my 10 Tasklist. But following is my Java code which returning me wired response.

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

String clientId = "[MYCLIENTID].apps.googleusercontent.com";
String clientSecret = "[MYCLIENTSECRET]";
String refreshToken = "1/P_mWwxnZEJHlDLiUs_BzMIvx6MDewDmvrgx-LNTfib0";

GoogleRefreshTokenGrant authRequest = new GoogleRefreshTokenGrant(httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken);        
authRequest.useBasicAuthorization = false;

AccessTokenResponse authResponse = authRequest.execute();
GoogleAccessProtectedResource access = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(authResponse.accessToken, httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, authResponse.refreshToken);

HttpRequestFactory rf = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(access);

String endPointUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists";
GenericUrl endPoint = new GenericUrl(endPointUrl);
String requestBody = "{\"maxResults\":10000}"; 
HttpRequest request = rf.buildPostRequest(endPoint, ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", requestBody));
HttpResponse response = request.execute();

String str = response.parseAsString();
utils.log(str);
```

And following is my response:

```
{
    "kind": "tasks#taskList",
    "id": "MDA4NTI1NjMwNTAxMTQ5ODQ0NzM6OTA1NjU0MjI6MA",
    "etag": "\"M3V2EYzE8ZKSrA5JDxxyFB0Dbp4/zpmuA0Fyh_wtIkaqHMXDWlYqzd8\"",
    "title": "",
    "updated": "2012-09-17T05:38:05.000Z",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists/MDA4NTI1NjMwNTAxMTQ5ODQ0NzM6OTA1NjU0MjI6MA"
}
```

I even tried with `requestBody` empty. But no use.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's my bad!

Instead of `GETRequest` Method, I used `POSTReques`t method.

Changed following line:

```
HttpRequest request = rf.buildPostRequest(endPoint, ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", requestBody));
```

to

```
HttpRequest request = rf.buildGetRequest(endPoint);
```

and its worked fine!